# Error while launching activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to make an Android Studio app that has more than one java file. However, when I was trying to run my app, it said:

```
Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.company.appname/com.example.company.appname.Text" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.company.appname/.Text }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example.company.appname/com.example.company.appname.Text} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

The Select/Run Debug Configuration also said "Text" was missing. I have a Text.java file, however. What's going on?

What my window looks like:
[image: no desc]

AndroidManifests.xml:
[image: !]

Comment: I think something is wrong with your manifests. Can you post your AndroidManifests.xml?
EDIT: Also check that your Text class extends Activity or AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest file you have declared only two activities (FirstActivity and Speech), but no Text activity.

Android cannot start activities not added in AndroidManifest.xml.

Cheers