# Error while launching app on Emulator - Android

Tags: android

```
07/30 13:54:19: Launching 'app' on Nexus 5X API 28.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.smstechnology.diceroller/com.smstechnology.diceroller.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.smstechnology.diceroller/com.smstechnology.diceroller.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while launching activity in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132529/error-while-launching-activity-in-android-studio)

Comment: I suggest googling the error message. You will find lots of other people have gotten the same error and have some solutions. See if any of them owrk.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and show your build.gradle file code where all the implementations are done?

Comment: @CodeDexter this doesn't really look like a gradle issue. The text shows the ADB command that was executed.